# watermark images

Tags: cms

I am trying to upload a small .png file via configuration > design in the cms. 
after upload, i get a broken image icon. when i log in via ftp, the image has been uploaded correctly. I have flushed all caches multiple times.Thanks in advance for any assistance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to FTP and give 777 permission to your uploaded image then it will show.

Comment: that was the problem. thank you very much!